# What does "be more mindful of the impact…” mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am reading an [article](https://www.thechangeforum.com/Personal_Mastery.htm) on Personal Mastery.

I am struggling to understand below the paragraph, this is first paragraph from the article.

> More and more leaders now connect successful business outcomes with their own level of 'Personal Mastery' – their ability to tune into themselves and be more mindful of the impact their patterns of thinking, feeling and behaving have on the people and situations that surround them as well as the results they get.

I am not able to understand definition of the *personal mastery* given in the paragraph below.

- **be more mindful of the impact their patterns of thinking**, feeling and behaving have on the people and situations that surround them as well as the results they get.

I am doubting if the word *of* is missing in the sentence after the word *impact*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the impact their patterns of thinking, feeling and behaving have on the people and situations that surround them as well as the results they get

> ... the impact XXX have on the people and situations that surround them as well as the results they get

The above construction is fine.

To add *of* after *impact* as the OP suggested, the expression would be

> ... the impact [of] their patterns of thinking, feeling and behaving [ ] on the people and situations that surround them as well as the results they get

The *have* after *behaving* is deleted.

**Edit After Comments From the OP**

Let's reconstruct to form the essential part after *Personal Mastery*.

> 1. their ability to ... be more mindful of the impact

What impact?

> 2. the impact (that) their patterns of thinking ... have on the people

The relative clause *that their patterns of thinking ... have on the people* refers to *impact*.

Combining (1) and (2),

> their ability to ... be more mindful of *the impact (that) their patterns of thinking ... have on the people*

The relativiser *that* is optional.

Comment: If you are still having trouble understanding the meaning of this sentence, you can think of  ' the impact ' here to  mean 'the consequences.'.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore, I am not still not able to understand. Why sentence is correct without of. Also  I am still not able to understand the meaning.

Comment: @novice, I have elaborated my answer.

Comment: @novice - if you want a word after 'impact' then it would be 'that', but it is optional.